# SQL WITH statement

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have the query below. How come with the invoice_dt set between 1/1/2021 - 5/31/2021... the output display ALL date ranges. How would I set it to look for dups based on pay_cte within the date range?

```
with pay_cte( vendor_id,invoice_id, pay_amt,pay_cnt ) as (
select vendor_id,invoice_id, pay_amt,count(*)
from ps_voucher
where invoice_dt between '01-Jan-2021' and '31-May-2021'
group by vendor_id,invoice_id, pay_amt
having count(*)>1)
select t.vendor_id, t.voucher_id,t.INVOICE_ID,t.gross_amt, t.INVOICE_DT
from ps_voucher t
join pay_cte p on t.vendor_id=p.vendor_id and t.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
and t.gross_amt=p.pay_amt
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would go a long way here.

Comment: What is the data type of `invoice_dt`?

Comment: The columns you join on are not unique identifiers, since you group them. So when you use those to join back to the original table, you get all rows conforming the join clause. The date column is not filtered anymore.

Comment: Where is your sample data? Maybe there are matching rows (your join criteria) in ps_voucher heaving dates outside that range.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your query is returning all dates is due to the fact that your actual select statement that uses the `WITH` clause does not have any filtering for dates. It is likely that your `ps_voucher` table has records in it that have `INVOICE_DT` values that are out of the range of dates about which you are curious.

There are two ways you can filter results; the first is in the (inner) `JOIN` clause, and the second is by adding a `WHERE` clause in the query.

Option 1:

```
with pay_cte( vendor_id,invoice_id, pay_amt,pay_cnt ) as (
    select 
        vendor_id,
        invoice_id, 
        pay_amt,
        count(*)
    from ps_voucher
    where 
        invoice_dt between '01-Jan-2021' and '31-May-2021'
    group by 
        vendor_id,
        invoice_id,
        pay_amt
    having 
        count(*)>1
)
select 
    t.vendor_id, 
    t.voucher_id,
    t.INVOICE_ID,
    t.gross_amt,
    t.INVOICE_DT
from ps_voucher t
join pay_cte p 
    on t.vendor_id = p.vendor_id 
    and t.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
    and t.gross_amt=p.pay_amt
    and t.INVOICE_DT between '01-Jan-2021' and '31-May-2021'
```

Option 2:

```
with pay_cte( vendor_id,invoice_id, pay_amt,pay_cnt ) as (
    select 
        vendor_id,
        invoice_id, 
        pay_amt,
        count(*)
    from ps_voucher
    where 
        invoice_dt between '01-Jan-2021' and '31-May-2021'
    group by 
        vendor_id,
        invoice_id,
        pay_amt
    having 
        count(*)>1
)
select 
    t.vendor_id, 
    t.voucher_id,
    t.INVOICE_ID,
    t.gross_amt,
    t.INVOICE_DT
from ps_voucher t
join pay_cte p 
    on t.vendor_id = p.vendor_id 
    and t.invoice_id = p.invoice_id
    and t.gross_amt=p.pay_amt
where
    t.INVOICE_DT between '01-Jan-2021' and '31-May-2021'
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to change your date for this format "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: 01-Jan-2021 --> 2021-01-01

Comment: The OP appears to be relying on an implicit cast to convert their string date values to date data-types; while this is bad practice, it will work (provided the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not change). [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e88f0393bd9b32430bc2fc7f453982e)